# webpack - Add dynamic param to chunks

Tags: webpack

I want to define a custom param in my HTML, that will be added to each webpack chunk.

I currently use `[name].js?v=[contenthash]` on all my files, but errors can still happen, as `[contenthash]` remains the same for dev/prod builds, and a few other scenarios.

The issue is that these files gets cached, and wont be invalidated for many days.

Would make my life much easier, if I could just update an static variable in the HTML.

E.g.:

```html
<head>
<script>
window.MY_CUSTOM_PARAM = '12345';
</script>
```

Chunks get loaded as `chunkname.js?v=12345`;